# Failed to queue test run 'xxxx 2011-10-20 13:00:00'. You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform the action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, visual-studio

I am trying to run my testcases in C# VS2010 but all of a sudden one fine day, it started showing me **Failed to queue test run 'xxxx 2011-10-20 13:00:00'. You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform the action.** error. Ic an debug through my tests though but cannot select and run it. The Tests results just shows up as not executed with this error message.

Some blogs told me to try the UnBlock button click but i do not see that option for any ofmy dlls.Is there is a specific path or folder i need to refer to?

If anyone has faced this issue and have a solution, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

My Test settings by mistake were pointing to remote, I changed it to Local and it started working.

Comment: Have same problem with unknown project. My test settings changes here: Load Test -> Active Test Settings -> MySettings.testsettings. Files location was in Solution root/Solution Items. So you must choose testsettings with Roles -> execution method -> local execution.