# Error in TFS Build: No permissions to add test run to queue

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, build

I try to run my tests (unit and ui tests) in a tfs build. I created a .testsettings file where I define to run my tests with the remote execution. The test controller is connected.

After start the tfs build, I get this error message:

**English:**
*No permission to add test run "MA-DEV$@MA-DEV 2014-06-03 14:46:25" to queue.*

**German:** 
*Fehler beim Hinzufügen des Testlaufs "MA-DEV$@MA-DEV 2014-06-03 14:46:25" zur Warteschlange: Sie sind nicht berechtigt, diese Aktion auszuführen. 
Informationen finden Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254169*

The link I get of the error message doesn´t help, because I do nothing with a Windows Store App.

**TFS:** 2013

**Visual Studio:** Premium 2013

If I run the tests from Visual Studio Premium 2013 with the testsettings file (is connected with the test controller), I get following error message:

*Failed to queue test run 'dbr@MA-DBR 2014-06-04 10:46:15': Der Server hat die Clientanmeldeinformationen zurückgewiesen.
Der Anmeldeversuch ist fehlgeschlagen*

Comment: [Grant a build server permission to serve a team project collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668757.aspx)

Comment: Doesn´t fix my problem, but thanks. Now I´m getting following Error, if I start the tests from Visual Studio 2013 with the testsettings file (is connected with test controller):

Failed to queue test run 'dbr@MA-DBR 2014-06-04 10:46:15': Der Server hat die Clientanmeldeinformationen zurückgewiesen.
Der Anmeldeversuch ist fehlgeschlagen

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842757/147211) help?

Comment: No, because I need the remote execution for testing on other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have the solution:

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh691189.aspx under "Enable you build agent to run unit tests" is the manual.

After that I get a similar error.

The solution:

You need to add following incoming rules to your firewall on the build server:

1:
**vstest.executionengine.exe** | Domäne (Profil) | Ja (Aktiviert) | Zulassen (Aktion) | Nein (Außer Kraft setzen) | C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\testwindow\ **vstest.executionengine.exe** (Programm) | Beliebig (Lokale Adresse) | **TCP** (Protokoll) | Beliebig (Lokaler Port) | Beliebig (Remoteport) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Benutzer) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Computer)

2:
**vstest.executionengine.exe** | Domäne (Profil) | Ja (Aktiviert) | Zulassen (Aktion) | Nein (Außer Kraft setzen) | C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\testwindow\ **vstest.executionengine.exe** (Programm) | Beliebig (Lokale Adresse) | **UDP** (Protokoll) | Beliebig (Lokaler Port) | Beliebig (Remoteport) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Benutzer) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Computer)

3:
**vstest.executionengine.x86.exe** | Domäne (Profil) | Ja (Aktiviert) | Zulassen (Aktion) | Nein (Außer Kraft setzen) | C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\testwindow\ **vstest.executionengine.x86.exe** (Programm) | Beliebig (Lokale Adresse) | **UDP** (Protokoll) | Beliebig (Lokaler Port) | Beliebig (Remoteport) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Benutzer) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Computer)

4:
**vstest.executionengine.x86.exe** | Domäne (Profil) | Ja (Aktiviert) | Zulassen (Aktion) | Nein (Außer Kraft setzen) | C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\testwindow\ **vstest.executionengine.x86.exe** (Programm) | Beliebig (Lokale Adresse) | **TCP** (Protokoll) | Beliebig (Lokaler Port) | Beliebig (Remoteport) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Benutzer) | Beliebig (Zugelassene Computer)